# Do you require sass in your gem if your using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the activeadmin gem and it should take care of installing sass when you do a bundle install . When i do a bundle show i can see that sass(3.2.5) exists. However when i remove sass from my :assets group my rake command fails giving out the exception:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- sass-rails
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/sass/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/activeadmin.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/activeadmin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:604:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/kc025858/webApp/data-source-onboarding/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.6/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/kc025858/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>
```

Why do you need to include sass to ur gemfile when you have already included ActiveAdmin ?

If you see the dependency.txt you can find that sass is a part of activeadmin.

```
activeadmin (0.5.1)
      arbre (>= 1.0.1)
      bourbon (>= 1.0.0)
      devise (>= 1.1.2)
      fastercsv
      formtastic (>= 2.0.0)
      inherited_resources (>= 1.3.1)
      jquery-rails (>= 1.0.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.13.0)
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but ActiveAdmin's site specifically states in its documentation you need to include sass-rails in your gemfile:

[`If you are using Rails >= 3.1, you must also include a beta version of MetaSearch and sass-rails`](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html)

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin has sass but not sass-rails in its dependency list, which is required to add sass adapter in rails asset pipeline.